# How to calculate the time average of the mean square displacement?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I’m trying to understand the mean square displacement (MSD) as calculated in time-averaged single-particle tracking experiments. For simplicity, I’ll consider the 1D case. Following [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349591821257), the MSD is defined as

$$\rho_{x} (n \delta T) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} (x_{i+n}-x_{i})^{2}/(N+1),$$

where the position is

$$x_{n}=x(n \delta T)|n=0,1,2,….$$

The data acquisition time interval is $\delta T$, and $N$ is the number of frames.

Can’t $x_{i+n}$ range well beyond what is defined? For example, if I wish to analyze all 100 frames of a 10 s video, the frame time is 0.1 s. Then $N = 100$ and $n = 100$. Then $x(N \delta T +n \delta T)=x(200 \delta T)$ is possible. Can someone please clarify this calculation?

Comment: Yeah this is odd. I feel like it should be $\sum_{i=0}^{N-n}\frac{(x_{i+n}-x_i)^2}{N-n+1}$

Comment: Exactly the same issue arises in the analysis of molecular dynamics simulation trajectories. MSDs for small $n$ may be calculated with more time origins, and hence better statistics, than those for large $n$. Anyway @AaronStevens comment is (or should be) the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done similar work with finding MSDs in particle tracking experiments. As discussed in the comments, the equation for the MSD for a given $n$ with $N$ data points should be

$$\rho_{x,n}=\sum_{i=0}^{N-n}\frac{(x_{i+n}-x_i)^2}{N-n+1}$$

This is because, as you have pointed out, you have $N+1$ data points, so it must be that $1\leq n\leq N$ (for anything meaningful). Think of $n$ as your "time lag"; it sets the time between points you are going to average over. The larger $n$ is, the fewer pairs of points you will have that are separated in time by $n$ data points.

In terms of the paper, it doesn't define what $N$ is, so I guess it is not saying you have $N$ data points. In the paper $N$ seems to be "whatever you need it to be for the equation to work".

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide a reference for the equation? I've seen some equations (for instance, Eq. (4.11) here: http://www.tneusius.com/pdf_verw/Dissertation_Neusius_2009.pdf) that start with the index at 1 and neglect the 1 in the $N-n+1$ denominator. As for the paper, it's widely cited, so it seems strange if it's wrong. I must also be missing something.

Comment: @idladle I don't really have a reference. It's just applying the definition of "mean" to the distance between all points separated by $n$ data points (separated by $n\Delta T$ in time)

Comment: @idladle I have edited my answer for what I think the paper is doing.

Comment: I have one more question: In the example that I gave $N=n$, so the summation is just 0 to 0, right? And can therefore be ignored? But I still would have to sum over all $n$. Is there some rule for selecting how big $n$ should be relative to $N$?

Comment: @idladle If $N$ is your total number of data points, then $1\leq n\leq N$ will give you something meaningful ($n=0$ makes each term in the sum $0$, and $n>N$ takes you outside of your data).